# Motion tracking : blank trackers in 2.69

Tags: tracking

I tried to do motion tracking in Blender 2.69, but whenever I place a tracker, the little window with the tracker preview is blank, and the tracker is lost immediately after I start tracking. I can only do it by hand, by placing the tracker on each frame.
I don't think this is caused by a weird video format or a rubbish footage because I tried with a video from a camera tracking tutorial and got the same problem. I also tried launching Blender from the terminal, but it didn't display any error.

Comment: Hmm... did you change the tracker settings a lot? Can you post a screenshot of all the settings and the footage?

Comment: I didn't change the settings, I even tried to delete the .config/blender folder, but this didn't work.

Comment: Can you post the .blend? Make sure to pack the blend first. It's under `File > External Data > Pack all into .blend`. Use http://www.pasteall.org/blend/ to post the blend.

Comment: Apparently I can't do that either... It shows an info saying 'no new files have been packed' and when I move the video to another directory, it won't display it.